# Set marker size in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

How can I change the marker size in plotly in R on a map? If I set the `size` argument to any number it makes it the same, too big size. And if I map it to a variable in my data, the markers are to small to really be able to tell the difference in the first place. Ideally I would like to increase the base size and keep the proportional aspect through mapping to the variable.

Reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

sample <- data.table(Region=c("Illinois","Illinois","California","California","Texas","Texas"),
                     code=c("IL","IL","CA","CA","TX","TX"),
                     Group=c("A","B"),
                     Value=rnorm(6, mean=100, sd=6))

sample[Region=="Illinois", c('lat', 'long') := list(40.3363, -89.0022)]
sample[Region=="California", c('lat', 'long') := list(36.17, -119.7462)]
sample[Region=="Texas", c('lat', 'long') := list(31.106, -97.6475)]


x <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = F,
  lakecolor = toRGB('lightblue')
)

sample %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode='USA-states'
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    y=~lat, x=~long, hoverinfo="text",
    color=~Group,
    text=~Group, size=~Value
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title='plotly marker map',
    geo=x
  )
```

Comment: @Hack-R Hmm works for me, and `plot_geo` is in the plotly package. Maybe a version issue with you?

Comment: @Hack-R Version 4.5.2

Comment: I'd like to make the points on the map larger (if that's what not what you meant by 'buttons')

Comment: `plotly::add_markers(<plot>, marker = list(size = <point_size>))`

Answer (score 9):

The simplest, and probably canonical way is to use the `marker.sizeref` attribute. You wrap this inside `marker=list(...)` like this

```
plot_geo(sample, locationmode='USA-states') %>%
  add_markers(y=~lat, x=~long, hoverinfo="text",
    color=~Group, text=~Group, size=~Value, 
    marker=list(sizeref=0.1, sizemode="area")) %>%
  layout(title='plotly marker map', geo=x)
```

[image]

Note that, the smaller `sizeref`, the bigger the markers. E.g with `sizeref=0.02` we get

[image]

Comment: @moman822 did this solve your problem btw? feel free to upvote and/or accept this solution if it was helpful.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to plot the size as a legend so it indicates an understanding meaning of the scaling/size?

Comment: @Ben you should ask that as a new question

Comment: Probably, but after a question a week ago that caused 6 down votes I'm not able to ask questions anymore.. :(

Comment: @Ben - its a good question though, so I asked it for you - here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383244/size-legend-for-plotly-bubble-map

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `size` is that you're literally specifying an exact size for all of the markers.

OTOH you can use the `sizes` parameter to proportionally scale the mapping between the base sizes and pixels.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

sample <- data.table(Region=c("Illinois","Illinois","California","California","Texas","Texas"),
                     code=c("IL","IL","CA","CA","TX","TX"),
                     Group=c("A","B"),
                     Value=rnorm(6, mean=100, sd=6))

sample[Region=="Illinois", c('lat', 'long') := list(40.3363, -89.0022)]
sample[Region=="California", c('lat', 'long') := list(36.17, -119.7462)]
sample[Region=="Texas", c('lat', 'long') := list(31.106, -97.6475)]


x <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = F,
  lakecolor = toRGB('lightblue')
)

sample %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode='USA-states'
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    sizes=c(1000,100),
    y=~lat, x=~long, hoverinfo="text",
    color=~Group,
    text=~Group, size=~Value
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title='plotly marker map',
    geo=x
  )
```

This is what the map looked like **before** the scaling (i.e. using the code in your question):

[image]

This is what the map looks like **after** the scaling (i.e. the map from the code above):

[image]

Of course, I chose the specific values pretty arbitrarily and you might need to tweak it. I'm also thinking that it might be advantageous to specify different colors for `A` and `B`.

Here's an example where I use colors to help increase the visual distinction between `A` and `B` while keeping the scaling proportional:

```
sample %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode='USA-states'
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    sizes=c(1000,100),
    y=~lat, x=~long, hoverinfo="text",
    color=~Group,
    colors = c("blue", "yellow"),
    text=~Group, 
    size=~Value
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title='plotly marker map',
    geo=x
  )
```

[image]

another variation:

[image]

and another:

[image]