# Set marker size based on coordinate values, not pixels, in plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

This post - [Set marker size in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859647/set-marker-size-in-plotly) - unfortunately did not help with what I was looking for, and is the only post on the topic I could find. Per the plotly documentation on the size parameter for scatter plots:

"size (number or array of numbers greater than or equal to 0), default: 6, Sets the marker size (in px)"

the (in px) is a problem for me. I'd like to create a plot where the marker sizes are based on the coordinate values, not pixels, that way I can increase the size of a graph (by full screening it, for example) and the points increase in size as well. An example of my code currently:

```
library(plotly)
mydf <- data.frame(x = rep(1:20, times = 20), y = rep(1:20, each = 20),
                   thesize = 10)
plot_ly(mydf) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', 
            marker = list(symbol = 'hexagon', size = ~thesize, opacity = 0.6))
```

If you create this plot in R, and then make the plot either larger or smaller by dragging the Rstudio viewer window, or in some other way, you'll notice that the markers stay exactly the same size (10 pixels), which is frustrating. I would love it if I could have these markers have diameter == 1 (on the x axis), rather than be set to a number of pixels. Is this possible?

Any help is super appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let's start with a plot with a defined axis range.

  ```
  p <- plot_ly() %>% layout(xaxis = list(range = c(1, 5)))
  ```
- Now add a JavaScript eventlistener which captures any changes in the plot's layout

  ```
  javascript <- "
  var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];

  function resize(eventdata) {
    // magic happens here
  }

  myPlot.on('plotly_relayout', function(eventdata) {
    resize(eventdata);
  });
  "
  p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(p, 
                                   onStaticRenderComplete(javascript))
  p
  ```
- The event passes `eventdata` from where we can get the new axis range.

  ```
  eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']
  ```
- Since we don't know the size of the plot in advance, we determine it via the size of the axis line

  ```
  var plot_width = Plotly.d3.select('.xlines-above').node().getBBox()['width'];
  ```
- We need to call the event once manually to make sure that plot is correctly initialized

**Initial plot**
[image: Before zooming]

**Zoom in**

[image]
**Complete R code**

```
library("plotly")
library("htmlwidgets")

p <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = c(1.5, 3, 4.2),
            y = c(-2, 1, 2), 
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines+markers',
            showlegend = F) %>% 
  add_trace(x = c(2, 3, 4.2),
            y = c(2, 0, -1),
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines+markers',
            showlegend = F) %>%
  add_trace(x = c(1.5, 3, 4.2),
            y = c(1, 0.5, 1),
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'markers',
            showlegend = F) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = c(1, 5)))
javascript <- "
marker_size = 0.5; // x-axis units
var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];

function resize(eventdata) {
  var xaxis_stop = 5;
  var xaxis_start = 1;
  var plot_width = Plotly.d3.select('.xlines-above').node().getBBox()['width'];
  if (eventdata['xaxis.range[1]'] !== undefined) {
    var update = {'marker.size': marker_size * plot_width / (eventdata['xaxis.range[1]'] - eventdata['xaxis.range[0]'])};
  } else {
    var update = {'marker.size': marker_size * plot_width / (xaxis_stop - xaxis_start)};
  }
  Plotly.restyle(myPlot, update, 2);
}
resize({eventdata: {}});

myPlot.on('plotly_relayout', function(eventdata) {
  resize(eventdata);
});
"
p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(p, 
                                 onStaticRenderComplete(javascript))
p
```

**Interactive JavaScript example**

- You could start with a defined height/width for your graph and a defined axis range, this way you would know how many pixels is one axis unit.
- The size of your markers would be initially in the size you want.
- Whenever a user changes the axis range, a `plotly_relayout` event will be triggered and you can retrieve the new ranges from the `eventdata` in `xaxis.range[1]` (start) and `xaxis.range[1]` (end)
- Based on the new ranges you can `relayout` your marker sizes.

```js
var plot_width = 500;
var plot_height = 500;
var margin_l = 100;
var margin_r = 100;
marker_size = 0.5; // x-axis units
xaxis_start = 1;
xaxis_stop = 5;

var trace1 = {
  x: [1.5, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: "markers",
  marker: {
    size: marker_size *
      (plot_width - margin_l - margin_r) /
      (xaxis_stop - xaxis_start)
  },
  showlegend: false
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4, 4.5],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 10],
  mode: "lines"
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1.5, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
  mode: "lines+markers",
  showlegend: false
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  width: plot_width,
  height: plot_height,
  margin: {
    l: margin_l,
    r: margin_r
  },
  xaxis: {
    range: [1, 5]
  },
  showlegend: false
};

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout);

var refplot = document.getElementById("myDiv");
refplot.on("plotly_relayout", function(eventdata) {
  if (eventdata["xaxis.range[1]"] !== undefined) {
    var update = {
      "marker.size": marker_size *
        (plot_width - margin_l - margin_r) /
        (eventdata["xaxis.range[1]"] - eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"])
    };
  } else {
    var update = {
      "marker.size": marker_size *
        (plot_width - margin_l - margin_r) /
        (xaxis_stop - xaxis_start)
    };
  }
  Plotly.restyle("myDiv", update, 0);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is along the lines of the workaround I've been using thus far, since I'm fairly certain it's the way I have to go with this. My current challenge is then automatically resizing the height and width of these plot_ly() graphs in RShiny. When height and width aren't set in plot_ly(), R Shiny dynamically adjusts the width (height is its own pain), but this is of course no longer the case when height and width are set.

Comment: anyhow, thanks as always for your input. I see your example is with Javascript, I will look to implement something similar with R code.

Comment: @Canovice: see updated answer with R code and automatic determination of the width.